# Error while writing data to MS Onelake from Azure databricks

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-databricks, microsoft-fabric

As currently it is not possible to create a shortcut in oneLake for private enpoint enabled azure storage so I am exploring another way to get the data from secure datalake to oneLake. According to MS [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/onelake/onelake-azure-databricks), It is possible to integrate azure databricks with onelake so I am reading the data from pe enabled adls and trying to write it to oneLake. While writing to oneLake, I am facing below error:

*Operation failed: "Forbidden", 403, HEAD, https://onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/d36-47c2-83e3-676eec7d9/22f90e-f0d9-4559008060a/Files/RAW*

I have used below code for it.

```
df_zipped = spark.read.format("parquet").option("compression", "gzip").option("header", True).load("/mnt/defined/measuremts-2019.gz.parquet")

oneLake = 'https://onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/d36-47c2-83e3-676eec7d9/22f90e-f0d9-4559008060a/Files/RAW'

df_zipped.write.format("csv").option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").csv(oneLake)
```

I understand that this is authorization issue so can any one of you please help me to understand how can I authenticate to oneLake from azure databricks.

I am accessing fabric from https://app.fabric.microsoft.com/ using Azure AD authentication so I am not sure how can I authenticate my identity from azure databricks to onelake.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you  created the cluster by enabling the
**Enable credential passthrough for user-level data access**
option in **Advanced options**.

[image]

Next, you need to give `ABFS path` instead of `https`.
To get `ABFS path` follow below steps.

Go to your workspace.

[image]

Then select your lakehouse.

[image]

There click menu option on **Files** and select **properties**

[image]

you will get below paths.

[image]

Here, you copy `ABFS path`.
Below is the data i am writing.

[image]

and writing it to onelake successfully.

```
oneLake = "abfss://Your_workspace@msit-onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/Your_lake_house/Files/"
df.write.format("csv").option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").csv(oneLake)
```

[image]

Output :

[image]

and again reading it from onelake.

```
display(spark.read.csv(oneLake,header=True))
```

[image]